# Jquery / CSS submenu

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to have my menu display a hidden menu between rows. I do not want a pure css menu. Please I realize this can be done with less markup, and it's missing lots. This is just cut and pasted, recreate.

Here is the html:

```
   <nav>
<div class="navigation_toplevel">
    <a href="Index"><h4>Home</h4></a>
</div>

<div class="navigation_toplevel has_sub">
    <a href="Index"><h4>Home</h4></a>
</div>
<div class="navigation_bottomlevel">
    <ul>
        <li>Preferences</li>
        <li>Preferences</li>
        <li>Preferences</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="navigation_toplevel has_sub">
    <a href="Index"><h4>Home</h4></a>
</div>
<div class="navigation_bottomlevel">
    <ul>
        <li>Preferences</li>
        <li>Preferences</li>
        <li>Preferences</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="navigation_toplevel has_sub">
    <a href="Index"><h4>Home</h4></a>
</div>
<div class="navigation_bottomlevel">
    <ul>
        <li>Preferences</li>
        <li>Preferences</li>
        <li>Preferences</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="navigation_toplevel has_sub">
    <a href="Index"><h4>Home</h4></a>
</div>
<div class="navigation_bottomlevel">
    <ul>
        <li>Preferences</li>
        <li>Preferences</li>
        <li>Preferences</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="navigation_toplevel has_sub">
    <a href="Index"><h4>Home</h4></a>
</div>
<div class="navigation_bottomlevel">
    <ul>
        <li>Preferences</li>
        <li>Preferences</li>
        <li>Preferences</li>
    </ul>
</div>
</nav>
```

I've set it up this way because this menu needs to be completely fluid (if the windoes small their may be 1,2 or 3 links per row), and be able to show submenu's horizontally underneath, filling the nav container.

My Jquery:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {


    if ($(".navigation_toplevel").hasClass("has_sub")) {
        $(this).hover(function () {
            $(".navigation_toplevel").nextAll("div:first").toggleClass("show_sub");
        });
            }

            else { }
      });

</script>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

well, `$(".navigation_toplevel")` returns a collection. The right way to work with a collection when you get elements by class name is `$(".navigation_toplevel").each(function(){ do something with a single element })`. But in your case I think you need a code like this: `$(".navigation_toplevel.has_sub").hover(mouseInHandler, mouseOutHandler)`